# Is it possible to open a project with Visual Studio from different machines?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

Earlier I asked a question, which has now been deleted. It was asked me of to come up with some different wording to my question. I'm sorry, but in this case I don't know how better to ask it then I have. Here's what I said:

> At work I've got a desktop with Windows 10 on it. Been working there
>   for 3 years. We using TFS 2015 with TFVC. Recently I was given a
>   laptop, but without enough disk space, so what I have done is on the
>   laptop I mapped a drive to the second drive on my desktop, where I
>   keep all of the Visual Studio projects I work on, that are in TFS. I
>   had hoped I could just open the project on the mapped drive from the
>   laptop to the D: drive on the desktop. But VS complained to me. So, is
>   it not possible to open the same project, on only 1 machine, but being
>   accessed both on the machine and by a mapped drive from another
>   machine?

Perhaps it would be best if I illustrated. On my desktop I have a project in my D: drive, so it's located in D:\Src\LRAT. Its in TFS 2015 and we're using TFVC on-premise.

On my laptop I've mapped the drive from the desktop, using D: on the laptop, as D was available. So, I get into VS 2017 on the laptop and try to open the project in D:\Src\LRAT on my laptop. However, trying to do that results in a warning message issued from Visual Studio (the complaint I mentioned earlier) which says:

> Team Foundation Server Version Control
>
> The solution you are opening is bound to source control on the
>   following Team Foundation Server:
>   http://ourserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection. Would you like to contact
>   this server to try and enable source control integration?

This confuses me a lot! I know that its in source control. Why is it asking me if I want it in source control? I want to be able to open it and use TFS/TFVC from my laptop against the same files and folders that are on my desktop. The dialog box that warning pops up in has 3 buttons, Yes No and Help. Clicking Help sends me to a very unhelpful link about Git and VSTS. I don't know what will happen if I click the Yes button, because that project on my desktop is already in source control, so I just click No because I don't know what else to do.

So, this leads to ask is it the case that in some way I don't yet understand opening a project created in VS 2017 and saved to TFS under TFVC on my desktop is different than opening that same project from my laptop connected to the D: drive on my desktop?

Comment: This isn't *directly* related to programming code. But regardless, when it's asking about "Enabling Source Control Integration", it's asking if you want VS to act like your version control client to pull and push changes to the repository on "ourserver". If you plan to edit code and have it available *and* not use an external client for pushing changes, then you should select "Yes", otherwise, "No". Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Sunny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The solution you are opening is bound to source control on the
>   following Team Foundation Server:
>   http://ourserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection. Would you like to contact
>   this server to try and enable source control integration?`

This kind of pop-up info, usually indicate there are some mapping issue related. Please double check your workspace mapping first.

Besides you could also try to connect your project in Team Explorer -Visual Studio follow below steps:

1  View->'Team Explorer'

2 'Manage Connections' (green plug)

3 'Manage Connections' (drop down) -> 'Connect to Team Project'

4 List of projects shows up from your account.

5 Select Project and Connect

More details take a look at this similar issue-- [Opening an existing VS2015 solution bound to TFS hangs VS2017RC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/3178/opening-an-existing-vs2015-solution-bound-to-tfs-h.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, Patrick. I'll check this out when I get back to work next week. I think you've answered my question.